# Issue on ios i am building an app on react-native getting error, error occur after adding react navigation

Tags: react-native

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

invariant
browser.js:38:14
runApplication
AppRegistry.js:193:13
__callFunction
MessageQueue.js:425:19
__guard$argument_0
MessageQueue.js:112:6
__guard
MessageQueue.js:373:10
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
MessageQueue.js:111:4
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
[native code]:0

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by running these two commands
cd ios
pod install